# Jetpack Compose, how to test navigation?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose

I'm quite new in testing and I want to learn how do I test navigation which includes Jetpack Compose Ui Screens with ViewModels. How can I for example test that when I click on button in Home Screen, it navigates to Info Screen? My ViewModels use Hilt dependency injection and @Inject constructor to inject appropriate repositry.

**NavGraph**

```
@Composable
fun NavGraph(
    themeViewModel: ThemeViewModel
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val commonViewModel = viewModel<CommonViewModel>()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.Home.route
        ) {
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>()
            HomeScreen(
                navController = navController,
                themeViewModel = themeViewModel,
                viewModel = viewModel,
                commonViewModel = commonViewModel
            )
        }

        composable(
            route = Screen.Info.route
        ) {
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<InfoViewModel>()
            InfoScreen(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                commonViewModel = commonViewModel
            )
        }

        composable(
            route = Screen.Saved.route
        ) {
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<SavedViewModel>()
            SavedScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel, commonViewModel = commonViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation specifically about testing best practices in Navigation Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#testing)?

Comment: This document don't provide informations about testing with HiltViewModel() and Hilt overall, which leads to many errors in my case.

Comment: So your problem isn't with testing Navigation at all (since, if you did follow that guide, you would have already avoiding passing the NavController down to individual screens and already have a callback you could override and verify that you navigated correctly) and your only remaining problem is with `hiltViewModel`?

Answer (score 2):

For hilt, It's the same with XML base project.

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class SurveyScreenTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun myTest(){
        // Your test functions go here.
    }
}
```

For navigation,

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class NavigationTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi::class)
    @Before
    fun setupAppNavHost() {
        hiltRule.inject()

        composeTestRule.setContent {
            navController = TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current)
            navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
            AppNavHost(navController = navController)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun yourTest() {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

You also need to set TestRunner for Hilt.

```
class HiltTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(
        cl: ClassLoader?,
        className: String?,
        context: Context?,
    ): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

and set this in gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.my_app"
        minSdk = Apps.minSdk
        targetSdk = Apps.targetSdk
        versionCode = Apps.versionCode
        versionName = Apps.versionName

        // add this part
        testInstrumentationRunner = "com.example.my_app.HiltTestRunner"
...
}
```

Check this document: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#testing

Answer (score 1):

You can see the codelab provided by Google [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-test-cupcake)

Comment: This codelab don't provide informations about testing with HiltViewModel() and Hilt overall, which leads to many errors in my case.

Comment: Is [this](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/writing-an-integration-test-with-jetpack-compose-and-dagger-hilt-8ef888c1a23d) article helpful to you ?

Comment: not really. The problem I have is that i don't know how to combine navigation testing approach from codelab provided by you and this article. The issue is that they both present different scenario, neither of them provides information how to test Navigation which uses HiltViewModels just like in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).